# How to inline JavaScript with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to use Thymeleaf to do inline Javascript.

For example:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  /*[[${myCode}]]*/;
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

and in Spring Boot I have this:

```
model.addAttribute("myCode", "alert("test")");
```

My output HTML is:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  "alert("test")";
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

which is a string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When [inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining), `[[...]]` corresponds to `th:text` and `[(...)]` corresponds to `th:utext`.

So

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
[(${myCode})]
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
[#th:block th:utext="${myCode}" /]
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is a totally old post, however right now I'm trying to figure out what's going on here.
So how did you manage to make this snippet workable?
At the time of development I'm getting tons of errors when I try to write such code.
At the runtime I'm getting empty (not even null) value there.