# Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, sts

I need to parse value from map into HTML template using Thymeleaf in Spring Boot.

This is my controller :

```
public class GraphController {

    @GetMapping("/displayBarGraph")
    public String barGraph(Model model) {
        Map<String, Integer> surveyMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        surveyMap.put("Java", 40);
        surveyMap.put("Dev oops", 25);
        surveyMap.put("Python", 20);
        surveyMap.put(".Net", 15);
        model.addAttribute("surveyMap", surveyMap);
         return "barGraph";
    }
}
```

This is my template :

[image]

I'm trying to map static data using the Hashmap in my controller as `surveyMap.key()` and `surveyMap.value()`.

But when running the application I got this error :

```
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "$,{surveyMap.key()}" (template: "barGraph" - line 40, col 27)
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:131) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:62) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.StandardExpressionParser.parseExpression(StandardExpressionParser.java:44) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.parseAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:220) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.EngineEventUtils.computeAttributeExpression(EngineEventUtils.java:207) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardExpressionAttributeTagProcessor.java:125) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleOpenElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:1314) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.OpenElementTag.beHandled(OpenElementTag.java:205) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateModel.process(TemplateModel.java:136) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.process(TemplateManager.java:519) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.LazyProcessingCharSequence.writeUnresolved(LazyProcessingCharSequence.java:85) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.AbstractLazyCharSequence.write(AbstractLazyCharSequence.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.writeContent(AbstractTextualTemplateEvent.java:224) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
```

Any solution please?

Comment: you should convert your map into a javascript array, can use javascript inline

Comment: hi cralfaro , could you please explain more ?

Comment: you could use a code similar to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189356/how-to-inline-javascript-with-thymeleaf and get the data from your map into a javascript array or matrix, then use it in your JS code xAxis, data properties etc