# How to retrieve the value of thymleaf dynamic id value using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

This is my dynamically changing thymleaf id. How do I refer that Id using jQuery

```
<div th:id="${answerList.answer_id} +'answer_id' " class="some class"></div>
```

I tried using this Jquery code it does not work for me. Please help me out

```
  $('#answerList.answer_id' + 'answer_id').text();
```

Comment: The short answer is: You cannot do that. Thymeleaf only exists on the server. It replaces itself with rendered HTML. jQuery runs in the browser. It does not have access to Thymeleaf variables (which have already been replaced by HTML).

Comment: Depending on what you _specifically_ want to do, you can place a Thymeleaf variable into JavaScript in your Thymeleaf template. See [JavaScript Inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#javascript-inlining). There are many questions and answers on Stack Overflow which cover different aspects and examples of JavaScript inlining - such as [How to inline JavaScript with Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53189356/12567365)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$('#' + [[${answerList.answer_id}]] + 'answer_id').text();
</script>
```